# How to Search in multiple OR conditions in Elastic search in Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have to do a search for all items in array along with a static detail in elastic search.

Fields in Elastics search index: `tech_id`, `detail`, `volume`

`tech_ids = ['qwe1', 'qwe2', 'qwe3', 'qwe4', 'qwe5', 'qwe6', 'qwe7']`

Number of tech_id in array can differ. 
Now my search has to take place in a combination of tech_id and detail where tech_id varies while detail stays static. This combination is an `or` combination. In the end i am expecting search to have with provided tech_ids and static detail.

```
tech_ids = ['qwe1', 'qwe2', 'qwe3', 'qwe4', 'qwe5', 'qwe6', 'qwe7']
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "detail": "calci"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "tech_id": tech_ids[0]
                        }
                    }]
}
```

Comment: @jaspreet-chahal Need your input bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after, I think, is a bool-should within a bool-must:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "detail": "calci"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": 
              [{
                "match_phrase": { "tech_id": tid }
              } for tid in tech_ids]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Assuming this works. How should i provide it with a loop. Because if array length is too long, it is going to be bit difficult to write each of it.

Comment: Updated my answer.